# Ways to print a string of an array

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char arr[] = "HelloWorld";

    printf("%s\n", arr+3); //first line
    printf("%s\n", &arr[4]); //second line
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me the following?

1) why is the output of first line = loWorld?

2) Why is the output of second line = oWorld?

3) Why is there a need to put & in second line?

Comment: Do you know pointer arithmetic and array to pointer conversion?

Comment: This is covered in all C books within the first couple of chapters - why not read it?

Comment: Yes this is simple pointer arithmetic. Go read how pointers and arrays work.

Comment: The expression `arr[x]` is equivalent to `*(arr + x)`. Considering that the address-of operator `&` and the dereference operator `*` is each others opposites, that means that `&arr[x]` is equivalent to `arr + x`.

Answer (score 6):

Your array is built like

```
---------------------------------------------
| H | e | l | l | o | W | o | r | l | d |\0 |
---------------------------------------------
  |   |       |   |
arr arr+1  arr+3  &arr[4]
```

So `%s` prints the string until it encounters `\0` character. You are printing from `arr+3` to end of string.

Note that `arr+1` is the same as `&arr[1]` , `arr+2` is the same as `&arr[2]` etc.

`&arr[4]` will give the address of the 5th element in the string(for pointer it is `arr+4`) and `%s` prints string from there until the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` means that getting the address of variable.So,the `arr` is as same as `&arr` and `&arr[0]`

The `arr+3` equal to `&arr[3]` and `arr[3]`